How to open a Visual Studio file in .NET 7.0 rather than .NET 8.0?
I have a file that has NuGet packages in, the packages can't be updated to .NET 8. Is there a way I can open the solution file in .NET 7 so I can get the packages working and view the solution?
When I click update packages they don't update at all.
The error is :

Error NU1202 Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer 8.0.4 is not compatible with net7.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v7.0). Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer 8.0.4 supports: net8.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v8.0) DataAccess C:\Users\holli\source\repos\EcommerceCompany\DataAccess\DataAccess.csproj


Can you retarget the project as .NET 7?

A solution isn't bound to a Net version. Projects are and they can be mixed in a solution. Visual Studio should simply open such a mixed Solution. What problem/error you actually get when opening?

Hello, it comes up with this error:
Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State Details
Error NU1202 Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer 8.0.4 is not compatible with net7.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v7.0). Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer 8.0.4 supports: net8.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v8.0) DataAccess C:\Users\holli\source\repos\EcommerceCompany\DataAccess\DataAccess.csproj 1
which is why I thought it was a compatibility issue

So the DataAccess project targets Net7 but the nuget package you want to use there is only Net8? The options are to retarget the DataAccess project to Net8 or use an older version of the nuget package that targets Net7.  You should decide on what the target Net Version for your complete solution is and then act accordingly.

@HollieManchester If you open the sln file and update the package via solution level, please unselect the incompatible project, take a look at my answer. :)

You will need to downgrade EF Core SqlServer package to 7.x

@HollieManchester .NET 7 and with it EF Core 7 go out of support in less than 1 month. EF Core 8 isn't broken. The error says that one of the solution's projects still targets .NET 7, probably DataAccess.csproj. The solution is to change the project's target to .NET 8, not go back to 7. If you can't open the project at all, you can edit the .csproj file and change net7.0 to net8.0

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

I am able to reproduce the issue you encountered:

From your description, you opened a sln file, and what to update the version of package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer. But the operation is unable to finish, right?
That is caused by there exists at least one uncompatible project and that package was been select to update.
So, the solution is to unselect the uncompatible project, after that, the update operation will be successful:

Take a look at the demo sln file content:
Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 12.00
# Visual Studio Version 17
VisualStudioVersion = 17.9.34723.18
MinimumVisualStudioVersion = 10.0.40219.1
Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "ConsoleApp16", "ConsoleApp16.csproj", "{A68682CE-6C33-4DFE-9A34-A22B6E8B8270}"
EndProject
Global
    GlobalSection(SolutionConfigurationPlatforms) = preSolution
        Debug|Any CPU = Debug|Any CPU
        Release|Any CPU = Release|Any CPU
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(ProjectConfigurationPlatforms) = postSolution
        {A68682CE-6C33-4DFE-9A34-A22B6E8B8270}.Debug|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
        {A68682CE-6C33-4DFE-9A34-A22B6E8B8270}.Debug|Any CPU.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
        {A68682CE-6C33-4DFE-9A34-A22B6E8B8270}.Release|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
        {A68682CE-6C33-4DFE-9A34-A22B6E8B8270}.Release|Any CPU.Build.0 = Release|Any CPU
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(SolutionProperties) = preSolution
        HideSolutionNode = FALSE
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(ExtensibilityGlobals) = postSolution
        SolutionGuid = {E34703CE-B4DB-4E83-A307-DA2ED99749A5}
    EndGlobalSection
EndGlobal

In fact it doesn't contains info of framework.
